# XSLT 1.0 accumulation, summing, multiplication

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a small fixed set of nodes: `<a>`, `<b>`, `<c>`, `<d>`. Each node can have a value of either 1 or 0.
Also, each node has a weight: 1, 2, 3, 4, respectively. Node attributes are not used.
How can I sum the value of each node multiplied by its weight using XSLT 1.0? Example:

```
<a>0</a>
<b>1</b>
<c>0</c>
<d>1</d>
```

Sum: 6

```
<a>1</a>
<b>1</b>
<c>0</c>
<d>0</d>
```

Sum: 3

```
<a>0</a>
<b>1</b>
<c>1</c>
<d>1</d>
```

Sum: 9

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete and short XSLT 1.0 solution. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This XSLT 1.0 transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:call-template name="sumWeighted"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="sumWeighted">
   <xsl:param name="pList" select="*"/>
   <xsl:param name="pIndex" select="1"/>
   <xsl:param name="pAccum" select="0"/>

   <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$pIndex > count($pList)">
     <xsl:value-of select="$pAccum"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:call-template name="sumWeighted">
        <xsl:with-param name="pList" select="$pList"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="pIndex"
             select="$pIndex+1"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="pAccum"
             select="$pAccum+$pList[$pIndex]*$pIndex"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied to the provided XML documents**:

```
<t>
    <a>0</a>
    <b>1</b>
    <c>0</c>
    <d>1</d>
</t>
```

,

```
<t>
    <a>1</a>
    <b>1</b>
    <c>0</c>
    <d>0</d>
</t>
```

and

```
<t>
    <a>0</a>
    <b>1</b>
    <c>1</c>
    <d>1</d>
</t>
```

**produces the wanted results, respectively**:

6

3

9

---

**Reference**:

If you want to get your hands dirty with really complicated math calculations using XSLT, see this:

**http://fxsl.sourceforge.net/articles/xslCalculator/The%20FXSL%20Calculator.html**

---

**XPath 2.0 / XSLT 2.0 Solution**:

Use just this XPath 2.0 one-liner:

```
   sum(/*/*/(number()*position()))
```

Comment: @Dimitre, could you also criticize my solution? I would really appreciate that.

Comment: @Flack: Your solution is a good one. It is a little more verbose than necessary. In particular, the weights aren't necessary, as every weight is just the position of the element.

Comment: @Dimitre, I think the assumption that weights can change is not totally pointless. Although not needed in this topic though.

Comment: @Flack: Correct. Speaking for myself, I always want to focus on the essence of the question and not provide extras that could distract and confuse. This is why my answer has its current form. The link that I provide as reference contain possibly the most complicated math calculations one can come-up with. So, if one is interested in going deeper, then they will follow the link.

Comment: @Dimitre, I wasn't judging and in fact upvoted :) I just wanted to get a little further for myself really, just for fun.

Answer (score 3):

Not really elegant, but that's what came to my mind.

```
<xsl:stylesheet
version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:my="my:my"
exclude-result-prefixes="my">
<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<my:node-weight>
    <node name="a" weight="1"/>
    <node name="b" weight="2"/>
    <node name="c" weight="3"/>
    <node name="d" weight="4"/>
</my:node-weight>

<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*[1]" mode="sum"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="sum">
    <xsl:param name="sumNumber" select="0"/>
    <xsl:variable name="thisWeight" select="document('')/*/my:node-weight/node[@name = local-name(current())]/@weight"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="following-sibling::*">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1]" mode="sum">
                <xsl:with-param name="sumNumber" select="$sumNumber + $thisWeight * number()"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$sumNumber + $thisWeight * number()"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to the following well-formed documents:

```
<root>
    <a>0</a>
    <b>1</b>
    <c>0</c>
    <d>1</d>
</root>
```

Result is `6`

```
<root>
    <a>1</a>
    <b>1</b>
    <c>0</c>
    <d>0</d>
</root>
```

Result is `3`

```
<root>
    <a>0</a>
    <b>1</b>
    <c>1</c>
    <d>1</d>
</root>
```

Result is `9`

Comment: +1 I like the fine grained traversal. But besides that the weigth could it be just a counter, I would use a variable for next node and calculation avoiding duplicated code.